# DownloadCompleteEvent fires twice

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, webclient

I have a windows form which lets the user select a file name and download it, Once the download is complete, a download finished event is triggered which unzips the downloaded file and processes it further.

The downloadComplete event seems to be triggered twice which is causing the unzipping action to happen twice. Is there a reason why the event would be fired twice?

below is the function which triggers the download and Handles the download complete event.

```
Private Async Sub Btn_download_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_download.Click
        
        Dim fileNameRows As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = datagridview_cloudContent.SelectedRows
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim fileType As String = AWSGlobals.CONTENT

        For Each fileNameRow As DataGridViewRow In fileNameRows
            fileName = fileNameRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString() & ".zip"
            Try
                Await DownloadAsyncFile(fileName, fileType)
            Catch ex As Exception
                CSMessageBox.ShowError("Content Import failed : ", ex)
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub


Private Function UnzipAndImport(filename As String) Handles s3obj.DownloadDone
        
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(AWSGlobals.ContentPath & Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)) Then
          
            Dim zipFilePath As String = DiskPath & filename
            Dim zipFileArchive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFilePath)
            Dim FullPathOfContent As String = DiskPath
            ExtractToDirectoryOverWrite(zipFileArchive, FullPathOfContent, True)
            ImportExport.BatchImportContent(New ArrayList(New String() {ExtractedPath}), objmanager)

        End If

    End Function
```

In the class that handles the downloads, the download method is implemented as below :

```
 Public Function DownloadAsyncFile(FileName As String, FileType As String)
           Try
                
                Dim Address As String
                
                        AddHandler fileReader.DownloadFileCompleted, Sub(sender, e) download_complete(FileName)
                        AddHandler fileReader.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf Download_ProgressChanged
                        fileReader.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(Address), AWSGlobals.ContentPath + FileName)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox( ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Function

Private Sub download_complete(filename As String)
        RaiseEvent DownloadDone(filename)
    End Sub
```

Can someone tell me if this implementation causes the download complete event to fire twice when just one file is being downloaded?

Comment: You're adding two event handlers each time you call `DownloadAsyncFile()`. Your WebClient object is created and stored somewhere else, you never dispose of it or remove the handlers.

Comment: Yes, I need the ```DownloadProgressChanged``` event to update the progress bar

Comment: Let's reword it: each time you call `DownloadAsyncFile()`, you add two **new** event handlers. Since you're storing the WebClient reference, why don't you add the handlers at the same time you create that object and remove the handlers when the Form closes instead? Do you need to handle concurrent calls to this procedure? Then use `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()` and enqueue a Task.

Comment: ok let me try that. Thank you!

Comment: If you actually need to handle concurrent downloads, ditch WebClient and get HttpClient.